# getItemViewType() of RecyclerView to return String

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Can We customize `getItemViewType()` of `RecyclerView` to `Return` `String`? Usually we get `getItemViewType()` of below type.

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }
```

Now I want the return type to be `String` in place of int.Is it possible?

Comment: what you have to tried?

Comment: I'm getting String (news, gallery,tweet etc) as Content-Type dynamically and according to the content-type,I've to display the layout specified for different Content-Type at positions.

Comment: so cannot you use some `Map<String, Integer>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    String type=dataSet.get(position).getType();
    switch (type){
        case "news":
            return R.layout.item_layout_news;
        case "galery":
            return R.layout.item_layout_galery;
        case "tweet":
            return R.layout.item_layout_tweet;
    }
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```